# adding binaries into docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Im trying to add binaries into a docker image.

Here is my docker file.

```
FROM ALPINE
ADD gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major-linux.tar.bz2 /
```

I build,

```
$ sudo docker build -t test1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  99.86MB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
ff3a5c916c92: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:e1871801d30885a610511c867de0d6baca7ed4e6a2573d506bbec7fd3b03873f
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
 ---> 3fd9065eaf02
Step 2/2 : ADD gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major-linux.tar.bz2 /
 ---> 1c64eaf65019
Successfully built 1c64eaf65019
Successfully tagged test1:latest
```

Then I run,

```
$ sudo docker run -i -t test1
/ # ls
bin                                gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major  media                              root                               srv                                usr
dev                                home                               mnt                                run                                sys                                var
etc                                lib                                proc                               sbin                               tmp
/ # cd gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/
/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major # ls
arm-none-eabi  bin            lib            share
/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major # cd bin
/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin # ls
arm-none-eabi-addr2line   arm-none-eabi-c++filt     arm-none-eabi-gcc         arm-none-eabi-gcc-ranlib  arm-none-eabi-gdb         arm-none-eabi-ld.bfd      arm-none-eabi-ranlib      arm-none-eabi-strip
arm-none-eabi-ar          arm-none-eabi-cpp         arm-none-eabi-gcc-7.2.1   arm-none-eabi-gcov        arm-none-eabi-gdb-py      arm-none-eabi-nm          arm-none-eabi-readelf
arm-none-eabi-as          arm-none-eabi-elfedit     arm-none-eabi-gcc-ar      arm-none-eabi-gcov-dump   arm-none-eabi-gprof       arm-none-eabi-objcopy     arm-none-eabi-size
arm-none-eabi-c++         arm-none-eabi-g++         arm-none-eabi-gcc-nm      arm-none-eabi-gcov-tool   arm-none-eabi-ld          arm-none-eabi-objdump     arm-none-eabi-strings
/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin # ./arm-none-eabi-gcc 123
/bin/sh: ./arm-none-eabi-gcc: not found
/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin # ./arm-none-eabi-gcc
/bin/sh: ./arm-none-eabi-gcc: not found
/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin #
```

As you can see from above, it says 'not found' but it is clearly there.

Does anyone know the proper way to do such a thing?

My plan is to add a bunch of drivers written in C for this embedded platform and use a docker container as an isolated development environment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

binaries are for ubuntu 16.04, changed to :

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
```

Answer (score 1):

The"not found" error on a binary that exists will typically mean that you have a missing linked library inside the container. You can use `ldd arm-none-eabi-gcc` to find out what libraries you are missing. With Alpine, it's often libc, since they use musl.